# Angular 2 calls a function 4 times

Tags: angular

Refer this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/dvisrE0RSyg7ZktAhMuU?p=preview).

It is based on angular quick start sample, here template is calling a function.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>{{print()}}`
})
export class AppComponent { 
  name = 'Angular';

  public print() {
    console.log(`Called`);
    return "Hello";
  }
}
```

The print function getting called 4 times, but the UI is only showing it 3 times. (Refer [this second plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/4MyPIj9BxMyYgzqnNeXm?p=preview)). With the second plunk, Angular does throws error *Expression has changed after it was checked.*

If I enable production mode, it gets called only twice.

My questions are:

1. Is there any way to avoid this? Or I should be aware of this and should not perform heavy operations in functions called by templates.
2. Is this due to digest cycles?
3. In dev mode, why the forth cycle does not refresh the UI, and why it stops at 3rd iteration but the function does get called for the 4th time?

Comment: It is called every time change detection runs. It is better to assign the result of the method to a property and bind to this property instead, and then use some event handler or whatever is appropriate to update the property when a dependent value changes.

Answer (score 1):

Its not at all recommended to use **`function`** in **`Angular2 bindings/interpolation`**.

you should use **variable** instead as shown below,

```ts
template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>{{myVar}}`


 name:string='';

 constructor(){
    this.print();        
 }

 public print():string {
    console.log(`Called`);
    this.name = "Hello";
  }
```

Comment: myVar = ''; is fine LHS type is assumed from RHS assignment.

Comment: @SamRedway sorry? what are you trying to ask or say?

Comment: in typescript, `myvar:string=''` -`:string` tells about dataType (declaration) part.

Comment: It is unecessary. Typescript is able to tell the data type by the RHS. So myVar = ''; tells typescript that myVar is a string. It is unecessary to have myVar = '' and also myVar: string = ''. It is clear that myVar is a string because you have assigned a string to it and the compiler can infer this. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html